# Techniques for having a node module return a "stream" of data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-streams

I hope I'm asking the question correctly, but essentially, is there a way in **NodeJS** to have a **CommonJS** module return a stream of data instead of a finalized chunk of data after a (long) computation? Assuming there is more than one way, what are those techniques?

For example, say I have a `findPrimes` function, written as a **CommonJS** module:

#### find-primes.js

```
/**
 * @module  findPrimes
 * @param {int} n - Find all primes less than this number
 * @return {array}
 */
module.exports = function(n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return [];
    } else if (n === 2) {
        return [2];
    }

    var primes = [2];

    for (let i = 3; i < n; i += 2) {
        let is_prime = true;
        let sq = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(i));

        for (let t = 2; t <= sq; t++) {
            if (i % t === 0) {
                is_prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (is_prime) {
            primes.push(i);
        }
    }

    return primes;
};
```

As you can see, this function returns an array of all the prime numbers less than its input. It returns the array *after* it has computed all those numbers.

So, say I go to use this module in a node script

#### index.js

```
const primes = require('./find-primes.js');

// Usage: `node index.js <num>`
let primes_less_than = process.argv[2];

console.log(primes(primes_less_than));
```

When I run the above script with an arg of `25`, I get the following (expected) output:

```
$ node index.js 25
[ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23 ]
```

However, say I passed in a much larger number, like 10,000,000

```
$ node index.js 10000000
# Takes a while to run before outputting the numbers...
```

While this works, ideally I'd like the program to start writing out the numbers it has computed before it finishes.

So my program would still take a while to run, but it would start outputting information to the screen much faster than "compute EVERYTHING first, then output ALL results".

What is the best way to achieve this effect? [Streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html)? [Promises](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)?

I'm open to any and all techniques for this, thanks.

Comment: Pass a callback maybe? ( the easiest not the best)

Comment: You'll have to use the Stream nodejs class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use the Stream class from nodejs, and the method should export a callback with a stream as the commentaries said:

```
const stream = require('stream');

function getPrimesStream(n, cb) {
    const primesStream = new stream.Stream();
    cb(null, primesStream);
    if (n >= 2) {
        primesStream.emit('data', 2);
    }

    const primes = [2];

    for (let i = 3; i < n; i += 2) {
        let isPrime = true;
        const sq = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(i));

        for (let t = 2; t <= sq; t += 1) {
            if (i % t === 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isPrime) {
            primesStream.emit('data', i);
            primes.push(i);
        }
    }

    return primes;
}

getPrimesStream(1000, function (err, stream) {
    stream.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    stream.on('end', function() {
        console.log('finished');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use Node.js's `stream` module for this. It's hard to answer your question within a few lines of code, but if you are *really* interested in how streams work, have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgEuZ52OZtU) (this is me giving a talk about Node.js streams at the Node.js meetup in Munich, Germany).

Alternatively, you may use a generator function with `yield`, but this as well is hard to explain from scratch in a few lines.

Anyway, *streams* and *generator functions* are the terms you should look for.

Comment: I guess if the OP knows what a stream is, then the OP also does know how to use callbacks… 

Comment: > streams and generator functions are the terms you should look for. Thanks, I'll also watch that video when I have time. Basically, I tried searching for techniques to deal with "displaying partial data calculated via node module" and streams seemed to come up, but I couldn't find any good examples (most dealt with HTTP requests). I'm wanting to get more comfortable writing proper node modules, so that is the context that I am approaching this.

Comment: BTW: Accidentally, within this talk, I had an example of how to use a stream to calculate prime numbers… ;-))) … starting at 36:09 - https://youtu.be/QgEuZ52OZtU?t=36m9s

Comment: Thanks for the video, I ended up watching most of it. Very informative!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice feedback :-)